# Android media player error (-4 -4) for playing .ogg files from res/raw

Tags: java, android, media-player

Weird problem here.. Logcat is showing me this (-4 -4) error in my media player code. I have a file `filename.ogg` in the res/raw folder of my application and I'm trying to play it.

Here is the code:

```
 try {
                        String packageName = getPackageName(); 
                        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( "filename" , "raw" , packageName );
                        mp.setDataSource("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + resID);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }
```

The toast message I see says:

`java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC`

In eclipse logcat I see:

`MediaPlayer    Error (-4 -4)`

Much thanks to anyone who can help with this... I just want to play my .ogg files from the res/raw folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( "filename" , "raw" , packageName );
                        mp.setDataSource("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + resID);
```

instead of resID have you tried R.raw.youfilename

Comment: Same error even when I do R.raw.myfilename. Plus I need to be able to go from string (a database entry) to resource. Any other ideas?